# Use the Magento 2 profiler in CLI

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, debugging, cli, profiler

In Magento 2 the profiler can easily be turned on with an environment variable

```
SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER [output]
```

with [output] one of "html", "firebug", or "csvfile"

Now if I want to profile a CLI script, i.e. a `bin/magento` command, this does not work. Of course, the "firebug" and "html" output formats do not make much sense, but "csvfile" does, which writes the profile result in `var/log/profiler.csv`.

I tried

```
MAGE_PROFILER=csvfile bin/magento
```

to no avail.

I found this code in `app/bootstrap.php` that checks for the MAGE_PROFILER environment variable:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER'])
    && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])
    && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'text/html') !== false
) {
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::applyConfig(
        $_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER'],
        BP,
        !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    );
}
```

And apparently it only activates the profiler for HTTP requests (excluding AJAX request)

#### This works:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT="text/html" MAGE_PROFILER=csvfile bin/magento
```

But it's a mere workaround. Is there another, more standard way to profile CLI calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there another, more standard way to profile CLI calls?

Apparently not, so I'll add my workaround as an answer:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT="text/html" MAGE_PROFILER=csvfile bin/magento
```

Comment: This is of course correct, unless you would like to consider using Performance Monitoring Tools like: Blackfire.io and/or NewRelic (This would required extra changes: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/troubleshooting/transactions-named-indexphp-or-unknown) in terms of CRON Jobs and CLI Commands

Comment: Can you provide some more information on where/which file we need to apply this workaround

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh No file at all, this is a shell command. It sets the environment variables HTTP_ACCEPT and MAGE_PROFILER for the execution of bin/magento